# Session returns with null after calling web service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

The service is working fine and return the correct response. the problem is if I use sessions after calling the service, it converts to be null out of the scope which I called the service inside.

Edit 1: after tracing, I found that there is a line in MyOperation method in the service which write a text into file *[ File.WriteAllText(Path, txt);]*, and if I comment this line, sessions works fine. any explanation ?

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    client = new MySvc.MyServiceClient();
    var res = client.MyOperation(); // If I comment this line, sessions works fine.
    Session["val"] = 2000;
}

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var foo = Session["val"]; // always null
}
```

Please help me with that.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the three lines of code in Button1_Click in a try-catch block or just the first two lines in the try block and the last line in the finally block.

There may be an exception which is not being caught which would prevent the next line (Session["val"] = 2000;) from being performed correctly.

Comment: thanks for your replay, I set a break point after last line. no errors happen and session load successfully inside the scope.

Comment: This does sound tricky. One other thing to try is to place some breakpoints in the global.asax file. Specifically the Session_End block and the Application_Error block. If the session is being cleared, it must go through one of those, which might give you more information. This is assuming the session mode is inproc. Good luck!